# android seekbar thumb (scrubber control) clipping when pressed

Tags: android, custom-controls, offset, seekbar, clipping

I'm having problems with a custom seekbar thumb (aka scrubber control). The thumb is clipping whenever I press on it, then goes away once I drag it. I've already added padding to the right and left of the seekbar to accommodate the thumb at the ends. This image shows what's happening at different stages of progress and while idle at either end:

[image: seekbar thumb clipping]

I've also tried adding a thumb offset to the seekbar: `android:thumbOffset="0dp"`. The result is no more clipping when pressed, but now the scrubber control does not move to the very end of the bar on either side. This image shows the seekbar with thumbOffset:

[image]

All of the scrubber control drawables are the same size, so the image size isn't changing size when the state becomes pressed. Is there some way to get no clipping while pressed and still have the scrubber control move to the very ends of the bar?

Comment: I think i saw a tumbleweed go by...

Comment: i hv the same issue. do you have an answer?

Comment: i like the style. do you mind sharing? :)

Answer (score 0):

Use PaddingLeft and PaddingRight and thumbOffset attribute for your SeekBar.

Comment: Please read the original post more carefully. I've already been using `paddingLeft` and `paddingRight`, and using the `thumbOffset` attribute produced the results in the second image: the clipping went away, but the thumb no longer can reach the end of the bar.

Comment: @Kanika For example if you'r glowed pin width is 18,try set thumbOffset 12 and say to me what's happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your `padding` AND your `thumbOffset` to half the width of your thumb.
I.e. if the width of your thumb is 30, set `padding="15dp"` and `thumbOffset="15dp"`